# Check status of running MongoDB map reduce jobs

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How do I check on the status of running map reduce jobs in Mongo DB?  My code can run Mongo map reduce jobs, but I'd like to have a status table, listing jobs as "in progress" or "complete".  How do I get that information from Mongo DB?

Comment: Did you try `db.currentOp()`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.  But how do I tell which entry came from my map/reduce?  I don't see the map reduce returning an opid.

Comment: Can you post the output of db.CurrentOp()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query for all running jobs using db.currentOp().

Usualy a Map/Reduce job has a few attributes you can query for.

A M/R job I just ran had the following stats:

```
"opid" : 258101377,
"active" : true,
"secs_running" : 4638,
"op" : "query",
"ns" : "<database>.<collectionname>",
"query": {
    "mapreduce": "<collectionname>",
    "map": function <randomname>() { ... },
    "reduce": function <randomname>(k, v) { ... },
    "out": { ... }
}
"msg":  "m/r: (1/3) emit phase 1235099/11558528 10%",
"progress" : {
    "done" : 1235099,
    "total" : 11558528
},
...
```

That's what you should look for! Especialy the "msg" attribute, that says how's the M/R progress.