# Back to back mapReduce jobs mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to run a back to back map reduce job every hour automatically. 
So every hour: 
startCollection---mapReduce1--->map1ResultCollection---mapReduce2--->map2ResultCollection

I want the mapReduce2 job only to start when the mapReduce1 job is finished.

How do i know when the mapReduce1 job is done and the mapReduce2 is good to go?

Comment: Normally by parsing `currentOp()`

Comment: I am using mongoDb in combination with node.js. Can u explain me a little more how i can test if mapReduce1 is done?

Comment: I am afraid I am no node.js expert however, this question should be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089664/check-status-of-running-mongodb-map-reduce-jobs